# Libarchive: how to compress an archive on windows?

Tags: c++, libarchive, lzip

I am trying to create a compressed archive on windows with libarchive and at the moment it is not working. I can create zip or pax_restricted(tar) archives without compression, without any problems.

To add compression I've tried some combinations of the following:

```
archive_write_set_compression_lzip(lWriteArchive);
archive_write_add_filter_lzip(lWriteArchive);

archive_write_set_compression_gzip(lWriteArchive);
archive_write_add_filter_gzip(lWriteArchive);

archive_write_set_format_zip(lWriteArchive);
archive_write_set_format_pax_restricted(lWriteArchive);
```

I've mainly tried using lzip compression with the zip format and gzip compression with the pax_restricted format.

First I'm not sure whether I should use archive_write_set_compression_* or archive_write_add_filter_*.

When I try add lzip compression and I step into the function I see it returns ARCHIVE_FATAL with the error message "lzma compression not supported on this platform".

When I try to add gzip compression and I step into the function I see it returns ARCHIVE_WARN with the error message "Using external gzip program". If I let the process go on the resulting archive has a size of zero.

I get the feeling like on unix systems there are system libraries for lzma and gzip that libarchive uses for compression and that these are not available on windows.

I built libarchive using the latest stable release, following the the instructions to use CMake etc. I didn't notice any errors in the CMake configuration like I was missing lzma or gzip.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got ARCHIVE_WARN with error message "Using external gzip program" on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS machine from a C++ program attempting to invoke libarchive-3.7.2. Solved it by manually building and installing libarchive-3.7.2 from sources. (The machine is locked down, so apt is not available). I suppose the program builds but fails because it is unable to load the archive library at run time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35213950)